# Add basic auth to Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui, sap-commerce-cloud

I have integrated swagger with SAP Hybris commercewebservices api extension for api docs.

This is entry in spring-v2-spring.xml :

```
<security:http pattern="/v2//api-docs" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/v2/*swagger*/**" security="none"/>
```

This is entry in springmvc-v2-servlet.xml :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="**/swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" />
```

How to add basic auth to swagger UI : /rest/v2/swagger-ui.html ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have configured it in the kotlin as below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .antMatcher("/swagger-ui.html")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic()
    }

    @Autowired
    override public fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("pass123"))
            .authorities("USER")
    }

    @Bean
    public fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable basic auth on swagger enable API, please use the below code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig
{

    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_URL = "/authorizationserver/oauth/token";
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_SCOPE = "basic";
    private static final String ZAMOK_AUTHORIZATION_NAME = "oauth2_password";

    @Resource
    private ConfigurationService configurationService;

    @Bean
    public Docket commonApi()
    {
        return createDocket("SFront Common API", "/api/(?!sop|cart|wishlist|savings|checkout).*");
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket checkoutApi()
    {
        return createDocket("Checkout API", "/api/checkout.*");
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket wishlistApi()
    {
        return createDocket("Wishlist API", "/api/wishlist/.*");
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket savingsApi()
    {
        return createDocket("Savings API", "/api/savings/.*");
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket cartApi()
    {
        return createDocket("Cart API", "/api/cart/.*");
    }

    @Bean
    public UiConfiguration uiConfiguration() {
        return UiConfigurationBuilder.builder() //
                .deepLinking(true) //
                .displayOperationId(false) //
                .defaultModelsExpandDepth(1) //
                .defaultModelExpandDepth(1) //
                .defaultModelRendering(ModelRendering.EXAMPLE) //
                .displayRequestDuration(false) //
                .docExpansion(DocExpansion.NONE) //
                .filter(false) //
                .maxDisplayedTags(null) //
                .operationsSorter(OperationsSorter.ALPHA) //
                .showExtensions(false) //
                .tagsSorter(TagsSorter.ALPHA) //
                .supportedSubmitMethods(UiConfiguration.Constants.DEFAULT_SUBMIT_METHODS) //
                .validatorUrl(null) //
                .build();
    }

    private Docket createDocket(String groupName, String... regexs)
    {
        ApiSelectorBuilder docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2) //
                .groupName(groupName) //
                .select() //
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withMethodAnnotation(ApiOperation.class));

        for (String regexp : regexs)
        {
            docket.paths(regex(regexp));
        }

        return docket.build() //
                .enable(isSwaggerEnabled()) //
                .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(passwordSecurityScheme())) //
                .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(oauthSecurityContext())) //
                .produces(Sets.newHashSet(APPLICATION_JSON));
    }

    private boolean isSwaggerEnabled()
    {
        return configurationService.getConfiguration().getBoolean("swagger.enable", false);
    }

    private OAuth passwordSecurityScheme()
    {
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope(AUTHORIZATION_SCOPE, StringUtils.EMPTY);
        ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant resourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant = new ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant(
                AUTHORIZATION_URL);

        return new OAuth(ZAMOK_AUTHORIZATION_NAME, Collections.singletonList(authorizationScope),
                Collections.singletonList(resourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant));
    }

    private SecurityContext oauthSecurityContext()
    {
        // @formatter:off
        return SecurityContext.builder()
                .securityReferences(oauthSecurityReferences())
                .forPaths(any())
                .build();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> oauthSecurityReferences()
    {
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = {};

        return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference(ZAMOK_AUTHORIZATION_NAME, authorizationScopes));
    }

}
```